# How to get the modular inverse by using Extended Eucledian Algorithm?

Tags: cryptography, inverse, modular

Given a mod b and find its inverse, then doing the extended GCD.

```
ax + by = gcd(a,b)
```

After I get x and y, how do I get its inverse?

Comment: You say "its" inverse. The inverse of what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `gcd(a,b) != 1`, `a` does not have an inverse `mod b`.

Otherwise `ax + by = 1`, which means that `ax = 1 (mod b)`, so `x` is the inverse of `a` mod `b`.

Answer (score 1):

Do this to calculate the inverse of *x* to the modulus *m*:

```
function inverse(x, m)
    a, b, u := 0, m, 1
    while x > 0
        q, r := divide(b, x)
        x, a, b, u := b % x, u, x, a - q * u
    if b === 1 return a % m
    error("must be coprime")
```

Here `:=` is the simultaneous assignment operator, so all calculations on the right side are done first, then all the assignments are made. The `divide` function returns both the quotient and remainder of `b / x`.